# Convert findViewById from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to convert this piece of code from Java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    genre[0] = view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre);
    genre[1] = view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre2);
    genre[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre3);
    recyclerView[0] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view);
    recyclerView[1] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view2);
    recyclerView[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view3);

    if (movieList.size()==0) loadMovie();
    else refreshList();

    return view;
}
```

to Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false) as Nothing?
    genre[0] = this.view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre)
    genre[1] = this.view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre2)
    genre[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre3)
    recyclerView[0] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view)
    recyclerView[1] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view2)
    recyclerView[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view3)

    if (movieList.size == 0) loadMovie() else refreshList()
    return view
}
```

The problem is that the compiler does not recognize the findViewById. How can I assign the recycler view in my xml to each variable?

Comment: What is that `as Nothing?`? Remove it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Is this in a Fragment or an Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/ 
You did not need in method "findViewById". Currently you can use name as a field of class. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

And now you can use welcomeMessage like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    welcomeMessage.text = "Hello Kotlin!"
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as it asks about "onCreateView" which is in a Fragment

Comment: The main problem is to associate view elements to variables. So, using findViewById is deprecated code, that actual only for Java. It is not principal where it will call in onCreateView or in onCreate

Comment: Yes and No. Direct addressing of the value without findViewByID works for the layout that is specified in setContentView. AFAIK, it does not wrk for inflated views.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of changes will work, I think.

Remove `as Nothing?` from

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false) as Nothing?
```

That may be unnecessary.

I don't get what you are trying to achieve here on initialising like `genre[0], genre[1]` ..

```
genre[0] = this.view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre)
genre[1] = this.view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre2)
genre[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.MovieGenre3)
recyclerView[0] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view)
recyclerView[1] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view2)
recyclerView[2] = view.findViewById(R.id.rc_view3)
```

instead you can try like below

```
val recycler_view = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
```

or

```
val recycler_view: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
```

or you may try extension functions as mentioned in the @TemaTre answer.

or <strike>you may use [anko library](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko)</strike>

**EDIT**

Anko is deprecated [see](http://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md)

Comment: I strongly advise avoiding Anko as it is deprecated: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md